# Git - excluir directorios al clonar un repositorio

Tags: git

Estoy trabajando con un repositorio Git remoto bastante pesado, ya que tiene guardadas imágenes y otros ficheros grandes, por lo que se necesita cierto tiempo a la hora de clonarlo, **¿hay una forma de clonar un repositorio Git excluyendo ficheros o directorios concretos?**

Comment: Hoy está pensado para almacenar lo necesario de una aplicacion de desarrollo.. cosas como imágenes grandes o ficheros grandes suelen ser específicos de una implementación de esa aplicación. Como tal creo que no hay un `git clone` para ignorar directorios del proyecto. Quizás sería mejor dividir ese proyecto y que esos archivos estén en otro repositorio, de manera que sean dependencias del primero

Comment: Busca algo relacionado con el fichero .gitignore, es justo para evitar meter ficheros en el repositorio, pero al menos te servirá para ponerte de nuevo en esta situación con tus propios proyectos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar a hacer lo siguiente:

```
mkdir <repo>
cd <repo>
git init
git remote add -f origin <url>
```

Una vez hecho eso ejecutas el siguiente comando:

```
git config core.sparseCheckout true
```

Despues tienes que indicar que ficheros quieres obtener del repo remoto. Para ello editas el fichero `.git/info/sparse-checkout`(lo creas si no existe).Puedes editarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
echo "algun/directorio/" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "otro/sub/directorio" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
```

En ese fichero tendrán que ir todos los nombres de los directorios y ficheros que tengas que obtener.
Una vez hecho eso, actualizas el repositorio vacio con el repositorio remoto:

```
git pull origin master
```

Solo te traerá los directorios que le has indicado anteriormente.